# MySQL Generate Random Data

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have some tables I need to randomize the phone numbers and Email addresses to be randomly generated for development purposes.

In MySQL how could I generate 7 digit unique random numbers for the phone numbers?

How can I generate random email address like `545165498@mailinator.com`.

How can I generate this random data with MySQL Queries?

Comment: Just use the MySQL string functions like `CONCAT`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL `rand()` Returns a random floating-point value in the range `0` <= `value` < `1.0`.

Multiply that by another number: `UPPER_BOUND` and get the floor of that, and you will get a random integer between 0 and (UPPER_BOUND-1) like this:

```
SELECT floor(rand() * 10) as randNum;
```

That will give you only one random number between 0 and 10.

Change the 10 to the number one higher than you want to generate.

**Something like this :**

```
UPDATE user 
SET email = CONCAT(FLOOR(rand() * 10000000),'@mailinator.com'), 
    PhoneNo = FLOOR(rand() * 10000000)
```

Comment: The only issue (might be a non-issue for you) with this solution is that it won't always generate 7 digit random numbers. This random number generator will generate numbers between 0 and 10000000. This means that the number 123 for instance could be generated in which case your e-mail address will be 123@mailinator.com, and not 0000123@mailinator.com

Answer (score 5):

This should give you a random number of 7 digits length

> SELECT FLOOR(1000000 + RAND() * 8999999)

And something like this should update your phone numbers and e-mail addresses according to your requirement

```
UPDATE Customers 
SET phone = CAST(FLOOR(1000000 + RAND(8999999) AS VARCHAR), 
email = CONCAT(CAST(FLOOR(1000000 + RAND(8999999) AS VARCHAR), '@mailinator.com')
```

Comment: Here it is without the varcar cast (which doesn't work for MySQL and some other databases, and also the RAND(8999999) part of it was incorrect (they were supposed to multiply by 8999999):  
UPDATE Customers SET phone=FLOOR(1000000 + RAND()*8999999), email=CONCAT(FLOOR(1000000 + RAND() * 8999999), '@example.com')

Answer (score 5):

### MySQL Generate random data walkthrough:

**Random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 exclusive:**

```
mysql> select rand();
+--------------------+
| rand()             |
+--------------------+
| 0.5485130739850114 |
+--------------------+                                                     
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Random int between 0 (inclusive) and 10 exclusive:**

```
mysql> select floor(rand()*10);
+------------------+
| floor(rand()*10) |
+------------------+
|                6 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Random letter or number:**

```
mysql> select concat(substring('ABCDEF012345', rand()*36+1, 1));
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat(substring('ABCDEF012345', rand()*36+1, 1))                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| F                                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Random letter a to z:**

```
mysql> select char(round(rand()*25)+97);
+---------------------------+
| char(round(rand()*25)+97) |
+---------------------------+
| s                         |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Random 8 character alphanumeric string:**

```
mysql> SELECT LEFT(UUID(), 8);
+-----------------+
| LEFT(UUID(), 8) |
+-----------------+
| c26117af        |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Random capital letter in MySQL:**

```
mysql> select CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25)));
+----------------------------------+
| CHAR( FLOOR(65 + (RAND() * 25))) |
+----------------------------------+
| B                                |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Load a random row into a table:**

```
mysql> create table penguin (id INT primary key auto_increment, msg TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into penguin values (0, LEFT(UUID(), 8));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from penguin;
+------+----------+
| id   | msg      |
+------+----------+
|    0 | abab341b |
+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Load random rows:**

Make a procedure called dennis that loads 1000 random rows into penguin.

```
mysql> delimiter ;;
mysql> drop procedure if exists dennis;;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> create procedure dennis()
    -> begin
    -> DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    -> myloop : LOOP
    ->   if (int_val = 1000) THEN
    ->     LEAVE myloop;
    ->   end if;
    ->   insert into penguin values (0, LEFT(UUID(), 8));
    ->   set int_val = int_val +1;
    -> end loop;
    -> end;;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)  

mysql> call dennis();;

mysql> select * from penguin;;
+------+----------+                      
| id   | msg      |              
+------+----------+                   
|    0 | abab341b |                 
|    1 | c5dc08ee |           
|    2 | c5dca476 |
...
+------+----------+
```

**Update all rows in a table to have random data:**

```
mysql> create table foo (id INT primary key auto_increment, msg TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values (0,'hi');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values (0,'hi2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values (0,'hi3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+------+
| id | msg  |
+----+------+
|  1 | hi   |
|  2 | hi2  |
|  3 | hi3  |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update foo set msg = rand();
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from foo;
+----+---------------------+
| id | msg                 |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 0.42576668451145916 |
|  2 | 0.6385560879842901  |
|  3 | 0.9154804171207178  |
+----+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an online tool to generate random data with many options.  http://www.generatedata.com/

Just enter the parameters to define what kind of random data you want, and export it to the appropriate format, then you can load it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what i was looking for :D